# Get closest time to current time php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have table like this:

[image: Database Image]

Assume current date and time is `2016-07-14 23:43:00`.

**Question** is I need to get next time after the current time. But it should be within the day. (`2016-07-14` not `2016-07-15`)

> Time will be user input so cant call it with ID.

Example: if I add the code it will gives me `2016-07-14 23:45:00`.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have no idea about this. Please help me.

> I use query like this for now. `SELECT * FROM video WHERE datetime > '$now'  ORDER BY datetime LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to calculate the start of the next day, and take values less than it.

```
SELECT * FROM video 
WHERE datetime > '$now'
   AND datetime < CAST(DATE('$now') + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY datetime 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: WOW !! Love it. Works fine. Sad is cant up-vote you ;(

Answer (score 0):

Use the same query but with limit 2

And You could use http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ to handle your dates on PHP in a fancy way

Check out your documentation